# VSCode の Live html preview で HTML のプレビュー表示が出来ません

Tags: html, vscode

Macで使用していますが、VSCode の Live html preview という拡張機能でプレビュー表示がされません。
HTML画面にてcommandやshift等を用いて入力しましたが全く表示されずです。

Answer (score 2):

もし [Live HTML Previewer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hdg.live-html-previewer) という拡張機能をお使いであれば、2020 年 6 月現在、この拡張機能にはプレビューができないというバグがあります。VSCode のアップグレードに伴って Live HTML Previewer が使っていた機能が[使えなくなった](https://github.com/HarshdeepGupta/live-html-preview/issues/25)ためです。

代わりに他の拡張機能を検索し、使ってみてください。たとえば [HTML Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tht13.html-preview-vscode) という拡張機能があったりします。

Comment: Live html previewです。何回挑戦しても開けなかったのはそう言う事だったんですね。別にある拡張機能教えて頂きありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0):

[image]
https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/html
こちらに記載の通り、プレビュー機能はついていません。VS Code Marketplaceで利用できる拡張機能があります。拡張機能ビュー（⇧⌘X）を開き、「ライブプレビュー」または「htmlプレビュー」で検索して、使用可能なHTMLプレビュー拡張機能のリストを表示します。
拡張機能を入れずに、作成中のhtmlファイルを叩いてクロムで確認しながら進めればいいと思います。

別途、 以下のページも参照してみてください。

[web制作が捗りそうな便利なwebツール【随時更新】 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/ta-ke-no-bu/items/c2b8b8b77555fbf50370)

Comment: クロムで開くことが出来ました！ご回答ありがとうございます✨

Answer (score 0):

angular ならこれ参考になります！
英語ですみません
https://medium.com/@MarkPieszak/debugging-angular-cli-inside-vscode-with-browser-preview-8dcc4b18ed64
基本的にbrowser preview と　debugger for chromeをインストールしたら十分だけどangularならjsonファイル設定が必要。

Comment: 単なるリンクだけですと回答とは言えず、削除対象になってしまうかもしれないです。[こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)を参考に。よろしければリンクを参考に日本語で回答いただけるとより良いでしょう。